# Preferred method for Materialized Views (Summary Tables) with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am developing a project at work for which I need to create and maintain **Summary Tables** for performance reasons. I believe the correct term for this is **Materialized Views**.

I have 2 main reasons to do this:

1. **Denormalization**

   I normalized the tables as much as possible. So there are situations where I would have to join many tables to pull data. We work with MySQL Cluster, which has pretty poor performance when it comes to JOIN's.

   So I need to create Denormalized Tables that can run faster SELECT's.
2. **Summarize Data**

   For example, I have a Transactions table with a few million records. The transactions come from different websites. The application needs to generate a report will display the daily or monthly transaction counts, and total revenue amounts per website. I don't want the report script to calculate this every time, so I need to generate a Summary Table that will have a breakdown by [site,date].

   That is just one simple example. There are many different kinds of summary tables I need to generate and maintain.

In the past I have done these things by writing several cron scripts to keep each summary table updated. But in this new project, I am hoping to implement a more elegant and proper solution.

I would prefer a PHP based solution, as I am not a server administrator, and I feel the most comfortable when I can control everything through my application code.

---

***Solutions that I have considered:***

1. **Copying VIEW's**

   If the resulting table can be represented as a single SELECT query, I can generate a VIEW. Since they are slow, there can be a cronjob that copies this VIEW into a real table.

   However, some of these SELECT queries can be so slow that it's not acceptable even for cronjobs. It is not very efficient to recreate the whole summary data, if older rows are not even being updated much.
2. **Custom Cronjobs for each Summary Table**

   This is the solution I have used before, but now I am trying to avoid it if possible. If there will be many summary tables, it can be messy to maintain.
3. **MySQL Triggers**

   It is possible to add triggers to the main tables so that every time there is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE, the summary tables get updated accordingly.

   There would be no cronjobs and the summaries would be in real time. However if there is ever a need to rebuild a summary table from scratch, it would have to be done with another solution (probably #1 above).
4. **Using ORM Hooks/Triggers**

   I am using Doctrine as my ORM. There is a way to add event listeners that will trigger stuff on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, which in turn can update the summary tables. In a sense this solution is similar to #3 above, but I will have better control over these triggers since they will be implemented in PHP.

---

***Implementation Considerations:***

1. **Complete Rebuilds**

   I want to avoid having to rebuild the summary tables, for efficiency, and only update for new data. But in case something goes wrong, I need the capability to rebuild the summary table from scratch using existing data on the main tables.
2. **Ignoring UPDATE/DELETE on Old Data**

   Some summaries can assume that older records will never be updated or deleted, but only new records will be inserted. The summary process can save a lot of work by making the assumption that it doesn't need to check for updates on older data.

   But of course this won't apply to all tables.
3. **Keeping a Log**

   Let's assume that I won't have access to, or do not want to use the binary MySQL logs.

   For summarizing new data, the summary process just needs to remember the last primary key id's for the last records it summarized. Next time it runs, it can summarize everything after that id. However, to keep track of older records that have been updated/deleted, it needs another log so it can go back and re-summarize that data.

---

I would appreciate any kind of strategies, suggestions or links that can help. Thank you!

Comment: Materialized views are views that can be indexed (called "indexed views" in TSQL/SQL Server terminology).  They are notoriously restricted in functionality, and MySQL doesn't support them.  MySQL barely supports non-materialized views, comparing functionality with other vendors.  Oracle is the only other DB I know of that supports materialized views, besides SQL Server.  I would expect DB2 does, but PostgreSQL does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted above materialized views in Oracle are different than indexed views in SQL Server.  They are very cool and useful.  See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm for details

MySql does not have support for these however.

One thing you mention several times is poor performance.  Have you checked your database design for proper indexing and run explain plans on the queries to see why they are slow.  See here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html.  This is of course assuming that your server is tuned properly, you have mysql setup and tuned, e.g. buffer caches, etc. etc. etc.

To your direct question.  What you sound like you want to do is something we do often in a data warehouse situation.  We have a production database and a DW that pulls in all sorts of information, aggregates and pre-caclulates it to speed up querying.  This may be overkill for you but you can decide.  Depending on the latency you define for your reports, i.e. how often you need them, we normally go through an ETL (extract transform load) process periodically (daily, weekly, etc.) to populate the DW from the production system.  This keeps impact low on the production system and moves all reporting to another set of servers which also lessens the load.   On the DW side,  I would normally design my schemas different, i.e. using star schemas.  (http://www.orafaq.com/node/2286)  Star schemas have fact tables (things you want to measure) and dimensions (things you want to aggregate the measures by (time, geography, product categories, etc.) On SQL Server they also include an additional engine called SQL Server Analysis services (SSAS) to look at fact tables and dimensions, pre calculate and  build OLAP data cubes.  In these data cubes you can drill down and look at all types of patterns, do data analysis and data mining.  Oracle does things slightly differently but the outcome is the same.

Whether you want to go the about route really depends on the business need and how much value you get from data analysis.  As I said it is likely overkill if you just have a few summary tables but some of the concepts you may find helpful as you think things through.  If your business is going toward a business intelligence solution then this is something to consider.

PS  You can actually set a DW up to work in "real-time" using something called ROLAP if that is the business need.  Microstrategy has a good product that works well for this.

PPS  You also may want to look at PowerPivot from MS (http://www.powerpivot.com/learn.aspx)  I have only played with it so I cannot tell you how it works on very large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Flexviews (http://flexvie.ws) is an open source PHP/MySQL based project.   Flexviews adds incrementally refreshable materialized views (like the materialized views in Oracle) to MySQL, usng PHP and stored procedures.

It includes FlexCDC, a PHP based change data capture utility which reads binary logs, and the Flexviews MySQL stored procedures which are used to define and maintain the views.

Flexviews supports joins (inner join only) and aggregation so it can be used to create summary tables.  Moreover, you can use Flexviews in combination with Mondrian's (a ROLAP server) aggregation designer to create summary tables that the ROLAP tool can automatically use.

If you don't have access to the logs (it can read them remotely, btw, so you don't need server access, but you do need SUPER privs) then you can use 'COMPLETE' refresh with Flexviews.  This automates creating a new table with 'CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT' under a new table name.  It then uses RENAME TABLE to swap the new table for the one, renaming the old with an _old postfix.  Finally it drops the old table.  The advantage here is that the SQL to create the view is stored in the database (flexviews.mview) and can be refreshed with a simple API call which automates the swapping process.