# Laravel relation between two tables with different incremental values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relation

This might be a weird question.

I'm building an anime/manga database app and I'm currently facing a relatively small problem - I have two models, Anime and Manga, each representing their own table in the database (obviously). What I need, though, is having a third table which specifies any relations between those two.

My schema for the 'pivot' table is as follows:

```
Schema::create('related_items', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('related_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('relation', 16);
    $table->char('item_type', 5);
    $table->char('related_type', 5);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The main problem, though, is that an anime can be related to another anime, OR a manga and vice-versa. I couldn't come up with a better solution than this, an example of a rows in this table would be:

```
id: 1
item_id: 1
related_id: 2
relation: adaptation
item_type: anime
related_type: manga
```

AND:

```
id: 2
item_id: 2
related_id: 1
relation: source
item_type: manga
related_type: anime
```

I'm not too happy about this. First off, I won't be able to use this in either of the two models - I'd have to create a completely new instance of RelatedItem. Also, I have to create two rows per relation.

Is there a way to do this better, preferably keeping the two tables (I know this can be done easily if I merge both anime and manga into the same table), as they don't have the same columns?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred method for Materialized Views (Summary Tables) with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150288/preferred-method-for-materialized-views-summary-tables-with-mysql)